# Using VBA to allow a checkbox to hide/show content in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I've gone through a number of tutorials and instructional videos trying to achieve my intended result of simply allowing a checkbox in my form to hide content when selected, or re-show it when being de-selected, but nothing seems to be working.

Currently, I've created a bookmark for the content I want hidden, and try to call his this in VBA with the following statement - which a number of resources indicated as the solution:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bookmark").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

But despite doing this, selecting the checkbox has no affect on the content.

Is there something additional I'm missing (I'm using Microsoft Word 2013).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked fine when I tested it, but I ran into a few issues since I've never messed with userforms/checkboxs in Word VBA and I suspect you may have the same.

For instance, the first thing I did was create `Insert --> Module`. This is incorrect. What you want to do is `Insert --> Userform` then drag a `checkbox` over from the `ToolBox`

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-check-boxes-word-54673.html

Then double click the checkbox to bring up the "module" it would run, notice there is no module in the side pane! Edit the module, then go back to the userform and press `F5`. You should be presented with a checkbox that will hide/unhide your text.

Here is my module:

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bookmark").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Here is an image:

[image]

Note: I didn't test how to insert the checkbox into the word doc, I'll leave you some of the learning!

Update:

This sub will make the CheckBox appear when run, but I'm  not sure the logic you would use to call it, perhaps an event like opening of document?

```
Sub Loadform()
Load UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This could be called via a keyboard shortcut or event, but this will cause a "pop-up window". If you want an inform checkbox you may need to look into using this Legacy Form/Checkbox. I was following the URL from above but I think it's dated.

[image]

Update:

You could also add this easily to a toolbar, but that isn't likely what you want. I found the best way is to use a "field code" see --> https://word.tips.net/T001571_Assigning_a_Macro_to_a_Button_in_Your_Text.html

I was able to get this to work by pressing `CTRL + F9` then typing `{ MacroButton Loadform ClickMe}` then clicking this text. This may be the best bet as using an image seems not to be a great idea.. (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-graphic-with-macrobutton/a9c1ef3b-cf1f-48ba-92a8-c44bffcdc131) & (http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/parts/macrobutton_fields.htm#Different_behavior)

Gif Example:

[image]

Comment: Can't figure out how to actually implement the checkbox into the word Doc, but additionally - From my understanding, doesn't using forms within Visual Basic make that created form act like a dialog window popup, or will it naturally appear in text?

Comment: That sounds correct, when I tested it was a pop-up window, I just added a macro that can be called to make the pop-up appear. However you may want to look into `Legacy Tools --> Control Group --> CheckBox` note that there is 2 checkbox's, you want the `Legacy Form` See Image

Comment: Well, I found a way to get it to work, but it's not a checkbox, it's text that loads the module.

Comment: I suppose you could do `[ ]` or something :P, hope this helps, it was fun to learn!

Comment: This suggestion is probably not working for the OP because it's not the kind of checkbox being used in the document.

Comment: You could just cut out the userform and have the X hide the text but that wasn't what OP asked